# Whats Wrong with this approach?

Tags: calculus, limits

I saw this question few moments back in here. The answer to this question is not 0 and is proceeded using Taylor expansion. I want to know where the error is in the below approach.

$\lim_{x\to0} (\frac{2+cosx}{x^3sinx}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

solving the above as follows:

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{2}{x^3sinx}+\frac{cosx}{x^3sinx}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{2}{x^4\frac{sinx}{x}}+\frac{cosx}{x^4\frac{sinx}{x}}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{2}{x^4\frac{sinx}{x}}+\frac{1}{x^4\frac{tanx}{x}}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{2}{x^4{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{sinx}{x}}}+\frac{1}{x^4\lim_{x\to0}\frac{tanx}{x}}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{2}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^4}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{3}{x^4}−\frac{3}{x^4})$

$=\lim_{x\to0}(0)$

$=0$

Comment: How do you go from $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{2}{x^4\frac{\sin x}{x}}+\frac{1}{x^4\frac{\tan x}{x}}−\frac{3}{x^4}\right)$ to the next line?

Comment: You cannot "move out" $x^4$ from limit, because the limit is about $x$ itself.

Comment: Using individual limits on $x^4$ and $\frac{sinx}{x}$

Comment: You will have to have limit for $x^{4}$ also which makes the first teem infinite. You cannot write $\lim \frac {\sin x} x=lim \frac {\lim \sin x} x=\lim \frac 0 x=0$, right?